# Error: Error: Exceeds block gas limit TestRPC

Tags: truffle, testrpc, genesis

I'm new to eth and dapp development and I'm running my own private test chain for development/ testing purposes and keep running into the above error when running `truffle test`.

Is there a way to increase the gas limit for my tests services? I have the following

```
testrpc '--debug --account="0xaa73b5c98e60d589e71ce7cff59c02f82e12c7ce676ee356da8e058a285ccd61,912082343256218" --account="0x52f3a1fa15405e1d5a68d7774ca45c7a3c7373a66c3c44db94a7f99a22c14d28,9023291452436789"
```

and my genesis file

`{
 "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
 "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "difficulty": "0x40",
 "alloc": {},
 "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "timestamp": "0x0",
 "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "extraData": "0x",
 "gasLimit": "0x8000000",
 "coinbase": "0xaa73b5c98e60d589e71ce7cff59c02f82e12c7ce676ee356da8e058a285ccd61",
 "config": {
    "chainId": 4224,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
 }
}`

- Would increasing the gas limit solve my problem?
- Can i set my prices
  so I can keep within the range of the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use provide the custom gas limit while starting the TestRPC or Ganache with the option of -l

```
testrpc -l 0x8000000
```

or

```
ganache-cli -l 0x8000000
```

Comment: Or `--gasLimit=0x1fffffffffffff` (13 Fs) if you want to use JS max integer, which is the max value supported in testrpc / ganache.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase the block gas limit, you can increase the value in `gasLimit` field in your `genesis.json` file and initiate your blockchain again.

Currently, your defined block gas limit is quite high (0x8000000 or 134,217,728) and you still have "Exceeds block gas limit" error. Did you get that error when deploying a contract or executing a contract's function?

Comment: Simple contract based on a tutorial. Got it to work eventually but will heed your advice is it comes up again.